# How to generate random value from enum and put it in array?

Tags: java, random, enums

I got an enum which is filled with "items" and I want to generate one random item of the enum and put it into my inventory, which I made out of an array. The array only has room for 10 ints.

```
public class InventoryEnums {
    public static void main (String[] args){

    int[] inventar = new int[9] // int array mit 10 Plätzen

    enum items {
        KARTE, MONSTERBALL, MONSTERDEX, FAHRRAD, VM03, HYPERHEILER, AMRENABEERE, TOPGENESUNG, ANGEL, TOPSCHUTZ
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to fill the array with random elements of the enum, or do you just want one random element? You can get an array of all elements of the enum by using `items.values()`. Note: `int[9]` *has room* for only **9** int's!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I first want to generate a random element from the enum and then put it into the array

Comment: If you only want one item randomly selected, why an array?

Comment: Enum should be named in the singular, and should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry I did a mistake. I need to generate one random possible alignment of the 10 elements in the enum and put that into my array

Comment: Define “one random possible alignment”.

Comment: for example the elements are : KARTE, MONSTERBALL, MONSTERDEX, FAHRRAD, VM03, HYPERHEILER, AMRENABEERE, TOPGENESUNG, ANGEL, TOPSCHUTZ  
so a possible random alignment would be 
TOPSCHUTZ, MONSTERBALL, MONSTERDEX, FAHRRAD, VM03, HYPERHEILER, AMRENABEERE, TOPGENESUNG, ANGEL, KARTE

Comment: How do you get to the idea that `new int[9]` will generate an array with ten elements? When you pass a size of nine, you get an array of nine. It’s as simple as that. And when you want to store elements of type `Items`, you need an `Items[]` array, not an `int[]` array.

Comment: @AmirKhan You need to fix both the title and body of your Question to make clear that you want *all* the elements, not *one* element.  And in the future, put more effort into drafting your Question clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enum should be named in the singular, and should start with an uppercase letter.

```
enum Item { KARTE, MONSTERBALL, MONSTERDEX, FAHRRAD, VM03, HYPERHEILER, AMRENABEERE, TOPGENESUNG, ANGEL, TOPSCHUTZ }
```

And I suggest you work at devising a more descriptive name than “Item”.

Get an array of all the enum objects by calling `values`.

```
Item[] allItems = Item.values() ;
```

Generate a random number. Use that number as the index into your array of all items.

```
int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , allItems.length ) ;  // ( inclusive , exclusive )
Item rando = allItems[ randomIndex ] ;
```

Or perhaps you meant to randomly sort (shuffle) all the elements of the enum. If so, make a `List` backed by the array. Call `Collections.shuffle`. Changes made to the list also affect the backing array. So the array is shuffled.

```
Item[] allItems = Item.values() ;
List< Item > list = Arrays.asList( allItems );
Collections.shuffle( list );
```

More briefly:

```
Item[] allItems = Item.values() ;
Collections.shuffle( Arrays.asList( allItems ) );
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Yvwhjo).

> [MONSTERBALL, TOPSCHUTZ, KARTE, FAHRRAD, VM03, MONSTERDEX, ANGEL, AMRENABEERE, TOPGENESUNG, HYPERHEILER]

Comment: You can use just `nextInt(allItems.length)` when the lower bound is zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a random integer value that is in the range 0 to array.length as

```
int rand = new Random().nextInt(items.values().length);
```

Then you can get the `enum` for the random value generated using

```
items.values()[rand];
```

You then use this in a loop to fill the array.

Comment: oh just realized you already posted similar solution like mine ! upvoting as this is another good approach. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want?

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        enum items {
            KARTE, MONSTERBALL, MONSTERDEX, FAHRRAD, VM03, HYPERHEILER, AMRENABEERE, TOPGENESUNG, ANGEL, TOPSCHUTZ
        }

        items[] inventar = items.values();

        int index = random.nextInt(inventar.length);

        System.out.println(inventar[index]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way:

```
  enum Item {
        KARTE, MONSTERBALL, MONSTERDEX, FAHRRAD, VM03, HYPERHEILER, AMRENABEERE, 
     TOPGENESUNG, ANGEL, TOPSCHUTZ
   }
   Item[] inventar = Item.values();
   Item singleItem = inventar[new Random().nextInt(inventar.length)];
```